# How to install pip package for a user when running as root in a script? (virtualenv)

Tags: python, linux, pip

I am logged in as `usera`.  I am trying to run a script, with `sudo`, from my home directory, and install some packages from `pip` for another user (i.e. `newuser`).

In `script.sh` I have the following:

`sudo -u newuser pip3 install virtualenv`

So the command I type as `usera` looks like `~/.usera: sudo script.sh`

For some reason this gives me the following errors:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/usera/.local'
The directory '/home/usera/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

And it does not install, at least not correctly.  Is there someway I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's print the `USER` and `HOME`:

```
(venv) ➜  sudo -u new bash -c 'echo $USER'
new
(venv) ➜  sudo -u new bash -c 'echo $HOME'
/Users/old
```

`sudo -u newuser` can change your current user to `newuser`,but it doesn't change your `HOME` folder which means you're running `pip3` command as `newuser` in your `HOME` folder.That's why you got  `Permission denied`.

So you can try this:

```
sudo -H -u newuser bash -c 'pip3 install virtualenv'
```

Or use `-i`

**-H, --set-home**

> Request that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to
>   the home directory specified by the target user's password database
>   entry. Depending on the policy, this may be the default behavior.

**-i, --login**

> Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry
>   as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such
>   as .profile or .login will be read by the shell. If a command is
>   specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c
>   option. If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.
>   sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before running
>   the shell. The command is run with an environment similar to the one a
>   user would receive at log in. The Command environment section in the
>   sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects the environment
>   in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.

See more details from [sudo manpage](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.19/sudo.man.html).

Answer (score 1):

In the script, try

```
sudo -i -u newuser pip3 install virtualenv
```

`-i` is for login shell so home directory will be newuser's now.

Comment: I am not sure where to put this. The idea would be to get this to work from the script and not have to run additional commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate your virtualenv. Do not create the Virtual environment should as a root (sudo) user.

Follow these steps

1. Create a folder (Assign all permissions to the non-root user)
2. Create Virtualenv inside the folder (without sudo) `virtualenv venv -p python3`
3. Activate the Virtualenv
4. You're good!